# On Linux browser cannot display websites after connecting to vpn

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, vpn, dns

On linux, after connecting to my VPN with cisco anyconnect, both my browsers, chrome and firefox, cannot display websites.  anyconnect is disabling sockets to the local network and cannot be changed.

On firefox, I get 'Server not found' in the title bar, and the page displays 'We're having trouble finding that site.'

On chrome, I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

I can resolve ip-addresses from the command line.

I can connect to a website on firefox if I use the ip-address.

Starting a new firefox instance (different profile) gets the same results.

If I use google's ip-address in chrome, it starts to connect, but then rewrites the url to google.com and then reverts back to DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

In chrome, clearing the DNS host cache, closing idle sockets, and flushing socket pools does not work.

I suspect that both browsers are connecting to some internal service which is failing.

Update: 13 May 2020

```
hostname google.com  --> works
nslookup google.com  --> works

traceroute google.com  --> fails
google.com: Name or service not known
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `google.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

Debugging traceroute reveals call to getaddrinfo() failing.  getaddrinfo() looks up value in nscd cache, and then opens unix socket to "/var/run/nscd/socket" which succeeds, but when it writes to the socket, it gets EPIPE and fails.

Comment: You state, "I can connect to a website on firefox if I use the ip-address." Then the issue is that DNS lookup fails. Nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: DNS is working correctly.  I can resolve hostnames from the command line.

Comment: "How to flush the DNS cache when using nscd: nscd is a name service cache daemon."

Comment: I know, lets flush the cache and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped nscd:

```
systemctl stop nscd
```

And not using the nscd cache has (for the moment) fixed the issue.